# C# linq query - Where with multiple ANDs

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to query using EF.  The user can use up to 3 search words but they are not required.  How do I write an EF query that will work as an AND for all of the search words that are used but be able to remove an AND for any search word that is empty?

Example, I want the following to return the first two elements in the array for s1='mobile', s2='', and s3='laptop'.  It's not returning any.  It should return the first two if s2 is changed to s2='burke'.

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
public class Simple {
  public static void Main() {
    string[] names = { "Burke laptop mobile", "laptop burke mobile", "Computer Laptop", 
                       "Mobile", "Ahemed", "Sania", 
                       "Kungada", "David","United","Sinshia" };

//search words
    string s1 = "mobile";
    string s2 = "";
    string s3 = "laptop";
    
      var  query = from s in names 
                               where (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s1) && s.ToLower().Contains(s1)) 
                                    && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s2) && s.ToLower().Contains(s2))
                                    && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s3) && s.ToLower().Contains(s3))
                                orderby s
                               select s.ToUpper();

    foreach (string item in query)
      Console.WriteLine(item);
  }
}
```

Comment: @Calculuswhiz I'm using a database in my application but changed to an array to simplify the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to write a single `where` statement, you can optionally extend an existing `IQueryable<T>` (or `IEnumerable<T>` like our code sample would be using) by chaining `Where` statements.

```
var query = names;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s1))
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Contains(s1));
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s2))
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Contains(s2));
}

// ... (or make a foreach loop if s1,s2,s3 were an array.

var results = query.OrderBy(x => x).Select(x => x.ToUpper());
```

Chaining `Where` like this is equivalent to "anding" all where predicates together.

EDIT:
To update why your specific implementation doesn't work is because your `&&` operators are incorrect for the given use-case.

```
(string.IsNullOrEmpty(s1) || s.ToLower().Contains(s1)) &&
(string.IsNullOrEmpty(s2) || s.ToLower().Contains(s2)) &&
(string.IsNullOrEmpty(s3) || s.ToLower().Contains(s3))
```

Remember that `&&` requires both left and right statements to be `true`, so in your case `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s2) && s.ToLower().Contains(s2)` this is saying that `s2` must always be not-empty/null.

Comment: I did something like this but it doesn't return results with all search terms.  It needs s1 AND s2.  This would return results if s1.Contains == true and s2.Contains == false.  I guess I could empty the result set if nothing is returned for any of the Contains.

Comment: No, it'll work the way you need, if both `s1` and `s2` are NOT empty, it will ensure it will only get results that contain both `s1` and `s2`.

For your given example, you should be using `(IsNullOrEmpty(s1) || x.Contains(s1)) && (IsNullOrEmpty(s2) || x.Contains(s2)) && ...`

Comment: @Heinrich I've provided an example showcasing why the implementation I've created is fundamentally different than yours, however, with the edit I've provided a drop in replacement for your logic should you want to continue with your format.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
public class Simple {
  public static void Main() {
        string[] names = { "Burke laptop mobile", "laptop burke mobile", "Computer Laptop",
                       "Mobile", "Ahemed", "Sania",
                       "Kungada", "David","United","Sinshia" };

        //search words
        string s1 = "mobile";
        string s2 = "";
        string s3 = "laptop";

        var query = from s in names
                    where (s1 != null && s.ToLower().Contains(s1))
                       && (s2 != null && s.ToLower().Contains(s2))
                       && (s3 != null && s.ToLower().Contains(s3))
                    orderby s
                    select s.ToUpper();

    foreach (string item in query)
      Console.WriteLine(item);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use an array or list instead of multiple strings, you could do something like

```
List<string> searchWords = new List<string>
{
    "mobile",
    "",
    "laptop"
};

var query = names
    .Where(n => searchWords
        .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        .All(s => n.ToLower().Contains(s)))
    .Select(n => n.ToUpper())
    .OrderBy(n => n);
```

This also is more flexible, as you can have any number of search words, without changing the query.